# Google no usa la meta description al indexar URL

Tags: html, seo

Tengo entendido que el hecho de usar una meta-description no significa que Google vaya a usar esa, puede considerar que otra porción de texto es más importante. El caso es que en el código tengo definido que la meta-description sea los 153 caracteres del artículo:

```
<meta name="description" content="PlayerUnknown’s Battlegrounds es uno de los juegos más jugados desde que salió en acceso anticipado hace 4 meses. En este tiempo ha conseguid...">
```

Sin embargo Google me ha cogido como descripción el texto que he publicado al compartirlo por Twitter:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de que coja la descripción que he indicado con el meta-description?

Edito para añadir todos los metas que uso:

tags of your website -->
    PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds bate record de usuarios en Steam

```
<!-- Google Authorship and Publisher Markup -->
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/110202439295145211518/110202439295145211518">
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/116771246502120537611">

<!-- Schema.org markup for Google+ -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds bate record de usuarios en Steam">
<meta itemprop="description" content="PlayerUnknown’s Battlegrounds es uno de los juegos más jugados desde que salió en acceso anticipado hace 4 meses. En este tiempo ha conseguido vender más de 6 millones de copias y generar más de 100 millones de dólares, pero lo que pudo ser una moda generada por los YouTubers, ha acabado siendo un género de masas, y tod...">
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://www.laxtore.com/imagenes/articulos/pubg_30_07_2017.jpg">

<!-- Twitter Card data -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@LaXtore">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.laxtore.com/noticia/229/PlayerUnknowns-Battlegrounds-bate-record-de-usuarios-en-Steam/">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds bate record de usuarios en Steam">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="PlayerUnknown’s Battlegrounds es uno de los juegos más jugados desde que salió en acceso anticipado hace 4 meses. En este tiempo ha conseguido vender más de 6 millones de copias ">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@egoicantero">
<!-- Twitter summary card with large image must be at least 280x150px -->
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://www.laxtore.com/imagenes/articulos/pubg_30_07_2017.jpg">

<!-- Open Graph data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds bate record de usuarios en Steam">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.laxtore.com/noticia/229/PlayerUnknowns-Battlegrounds-bate-record-de-usuarios-en-Steam">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.laxtore.com/imagenes/articulos/pubg_30_07_2017.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="PlayerUnknown’s Battlegrounds es uno de los juegos más jugados desde que salió en acceso anticipado hace 4 meses. En este tiempo ha conseguido vender más de 6 millones de copias y generar más de 100 millones de dólares, pero lo que pudo ser una moda generada por los YouTubers, ha acabado siendo un género de masas, y tod...">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="LaXtore">
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2017-07-31 14:01:47">
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2017-07-31 14:01:47">
<meta property="article:section" content="Article Section">
<meta property="article:tag" content="Article Tag">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="EgoiCantero">
```

Comment: ¿Tienes definidos los valores de microdatos de Schema.org?¿Tienes meta etiquetas de OpenGraph en tu página?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Acabo de editar la pregunta añadiendo los metas que uso.

Comment: La meta description es muy importante para el SEO. Una description entrecortada, como la tienes ahora, es terrible. Y es importante que cumplas con la norma: 150 caracteres como máximo. Google tiene [una herramienta](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80407) para revisar posibles problemas en tu página. Lo que puede estar ocurriendo es que Google esté optando por una meta description _mejor_ que la actual, eso se puede evitar usando [`<meta name="nosnippets">`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624#nosnippet) Creo que la solución es **dedicarle tiempo a escribirla bien**

Comment: @A.Cedano Me has dejado descolado con lo de 150 caracteres, pensaba que eran 156 en total, son al menos los caracteres que tiene de límite el plugin Yoast SEO de WordPress, que lo estaba usando para obtener mejores resultados. ¿Recomiendas que en vez de tenerlo puesto siempre para que me coja los 156 caracteres (o 150 como comentas), lo meta manualmente? Entiendo que es mejor porque puedes optimizar la meta-description.

Comment: Bueno, me dejas descolocado con los 156. Yo uso el framework Thesis y me marca un límite de 150 caracteres. En la red aparecen artículos diciendo que hace aproximadamente un año Google extendió el tamaño máximo de los `meta description`. A mi esa parte me va muy bien con Thesis (sólo que es de pago). En cuanto a Yoast y los plugins en general no confío mucho en ellos. Si trabajas en el diseño web o incluso para proyectos personales, conviene pagar una licencia de por vida con Thesis. El problema de Yoast es que al tener todos tus posts dependiendo de ellos, puedes ser su esclavo toda la vida.

Comment: [Esta solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92479/2089) ayudó a resolver su problema @JetLagFox ?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes alguno `item scope` seleccionado en tu `head` o en la etiqueta `<html>` que sería lo adecuado y recomendado para un *scope* de mayor alcance?

Cuando agregas tags `itemprop`, estas deben ser envueltas por un contenedor principal que contiene las duas seguientes tags:

```
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"
```

> **Nota:** Si tu sitio web no acepta etiquetas sin estaren cerradas, puedes hacer algo como esto: `itemscope="itemscope"`

Donde esta el `"Event"` al final del enlace, en lugar de esto debe ser el parámetro deseado para definir el tipo de tipo de página como quieres describir tu página.

> ### Ejemplos de `itemtype`
>
> Si es un sitio web - `https://schema.org/WebSite`
> Si es una página de artículo - `https://schema.org/Article`
> Si es una página de película - `https://schema.org/Movie`
> *etcétera... Leer más en [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemscope_itemtype)*

Como los ejemplos mostrados en **[schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemscope_itemtype)**, esto es cómo las etiquetas deben parecerse si la información estaba en algún lugar alrededor del cuerpo del sitio web

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <div itemprop="name">Spinal Tap</div>
  <span itemprop="description">One of the loudest bands ever
  reunites for an unforgettable two-day show.</span>
  Event date:
  <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2011-05-08T19:30">May 8, 7:30pm</time>
</div>
```

Siempre envuelto con un elemento padre con `"itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/...'"`

Así lo mismo se aplica a las `meta-tags itemprop`, si no hay un `itemscope` e `itemtype` previamente definido la información no será verificada como se esperaba.

#### Que debería ser algo como:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Game">
  <head>
    <!-- Schema.org markup for Google+ -->
    <meta itemprop="name" content="PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="descripción...">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="image.jpg">
  </head>
</html>
```

Utilizando *scope* en `<html>` para tener un mayor alcance de `itemscope`, caso tengas otras informaciónes `itemprop` almacenada alrededor del documento.

### Depuración de datos

Una vez hecho esto, puede comprobar si todo funciona correctamente utilizando esta herramienta para ver si hay algún error en sus datos estructurados: **[Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)**
Que básicamente es un "**Facebook Debugger Tool**" para el **Google**

> **Tenga en cuenta** que después de hacer esto, puede tardar algunos días en actualizar la descripción de la página en las búsquedas de Google. Pero si puedes ver la descripción en la Herramienta de Datos Estructurados y no se produce ningún error, entonces todo está okay.